# Any established practices for implementing coordinated operations across multiple APIs?

Tags: rest, api, websocket, microservices

Writing a service that has to talk to multiple APIs and also do some transactions to DB. Obviously any of the whole sequence of async calls might fail and then I guess I would have to rollback the steps that have completed so far. In the case of DB the obvious solution to the task would be to use transactions. So if any of the steps fail - transaction simply gets rolled back. But what about the same thing happening in the hybrid distributed environment.

What are best practices here? Are there any at all?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "hybrid distributed environment"? Do you mean a distributed system using micro-services or something more specific?

Comment: I mean that some calls have to be made over Rest API, some over websocket, etc.

Comment: Please have a look at my answer here(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58178511/how-to-rollback-microservices/58186038#58186038) which explains the Saga Pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that you have that hybrid distributed environment and Two-Phase Commit transactions are
not valid options you could apply the **Saga Pattern**.

The basic idea is to make your services/modules execute local transactions and coordinate the distributed transaction among them providing compensation operations to undo operations when necessary.

It is a complicated pattern and adds a lot of complexity to your system. However it provides a well designed solutions for that problem.

**References:**

- https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html
- https://blog.couchbase.com/saga-pattern-implement-business-transactions-using-microservices-part/

Comment: I was thinking of something like that - `RevertableOperation`, that takes in two promises, one to execute operation and another to roll it back.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of if you use only rest API for communication or other protocols or methods like Web Sockets as well you can apply the Saga Pattern.

The implementation would require an abstraction for the different type of calls but it would still be considered a Saga pattern.
The orchestration of the Saga is still on application level so you can control it regardless of if it is REST, WebSockets, WSDL or something else.

In a addition to Leonardo's provided sources please have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58178511/how-to-rollback-microservices/58186038#58186038).